Question regarding academic qualifications requirement of Chancenkarte (Opportunity Card)
I posted a question earlier in which I explained my situation a bit:
Can I go for a PhD in Germany with a record of being homeless and being admitted to the hospital for mental health reasons in Toronto?.
A summary: I am Bangladeshi and currently reside in Bangladesh. I completed 108 credits out of 120 credits in a 4 year BSc degree in Computer Science and Math at a top 5 University in Canada as an international student. Unfortunately due to financial troubles relating to covid I had to drop out and return to my own country (was not deported, left before visa expired).
In Bangladesh I got a scholarship at a local university to restart my Bachelors degree. In my second year now, unfortunately they don't accept credit transfers. In a previous question I asked about applying for a PhD in Germany, however this question is a bit different:
I got to learn about the Opportunity Card. Since I was gonna apply for a PhD to Germany anyways, I am gonna start learning German starting January. Now I am thinking of applying for the Opportunity Card in a year after learning German. I also have 3 years of work experience as a Software Developer. I looked at the minimum requirements for the Opportunity Card, it says you need at least a 2 year educational qualification if not a full 4 year degree. (forgot the exact wording) My question is will my unfinished degree in Canada, where I completed 108 credits out of 120 credits in a 4 year BSc in Computer Science count as meeting the minimum educational qualifications ?
I understand that it is an unfinished qualification, however it amounts of a little more than 3.5 years out of the 4 years of the whole degree. I was thinking of sending it to the ZAB for evaluation to see if it would fulfill the minimum 2 year educational requirement.

The opportunity card seems designed to create an immigration path for experienced workers in fields that have lower educational requirements and compensation than IT (especially healthcare or regulated trades). There are several other options for IT professionals but they have stricter requirements. A finished diploma is a clear-cut requirements for the Chancenkarte but even if you had one, it doesn't seem to fit your situation or project very well.

Got it. Thanks for the answer.

The requirement is explicitly about completing a two-year degree or qualification so it's a complete non-starter for you. Having completed the relevant education is a hard requirement even if you qualify through the point systems. There is no ambiguity about that on the official make-it-in-germany website or the letter of the law.

Got it. Thanks for the answer.
